# NSDictionary array of same key

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, soap, nsdictionary

I'm requesting a SOAP `Webservice` and I parse the response to a `NSDictionary`. The XML response has multiple unique keys. Here's an example (already parse on the dictionary):

```
"typ:partits" =             {
            "typ:dadesPartit" =                 {
                "typ:aforament" = 1;
                "typ:codiEsdeveniment" = 2;
                "typ:competicio" = GAMPER;
                "typ:dataHoraConfirmada" = false;
                "typ:dataPartit" = "08/18/14";
                "typ:descripcioPartit" = "FCBARCELONA - CLUB LEON F.C.";
                "typ:horaPartit" = "9:30:00 PM";
                "typ:jornada" = 99;
                "typ:partitActiuMenor" = true;
                "typ:temporada" = "2014-2015";
                "typ:tipusEsdeveniment" = 0;
            },
            "typ:dadesPartit" =                 {
                "typ:aforament" = 1;
                "typ:codiEsdeveniment" = 2;
                "typ:competicio" = GAMPER;
                "typ:dataHoraConfirmada" = false;
                "typ:dataPartit" = "08/26/14";
                "typ:descripcioPartit" = "FCBARCELONA - REAL MADRID";
                "typ:horaPartit" = "9:30:00 PM";
                "typ:jornada" = 101;
                "typ:partitActiuMenor" = true;
                "typ:temporada" = "2014-2015";
                "typ:tipusEsdeveniment" = 0;
            };
        };
```

How can I iterate through these keys?, they are the same :( ...

I tried with "allObjects" but when I receive only one "typ:dadesPartit" object it treats it like an `array` instead of a `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Is it a log of NSDictionary? I thought the key must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is returning one type as both your keys are same, 
Try renaming the keys to separate names, and the values associated with those keys will come when u type allKeys

Comment: Its coming from a Soap webservice, the response should be changed from the webservice, not from the app.

Comment: then you should set a bug to the web service(from where u are fetching the database) and should tell them about it, that NSDictionary has to have different keys for different values.
Keys must be unique

Comment: please tick as answer accepted if u think the answer helped